# Emacs fixme mode on javascript

Tags: emacs, elisp

I just got fixme-mode.el, and loaded it. It works just fine on C, Lisp and other languages. But it doesn't work on Javascript.

```
(defcustom fixme-modes '(erlang-mode java-mode c-mode emacs-lisp-mode jde-mode
                                  scheme-mode python-mode ruby-mode cperl-mode
                                  slime-mode common-lisp-mode c++-mode d-mode
                                  js2-mode haskell-mode tuareg-mode lua-mode
                                  pascal-mode fortran-mode prolog-mode asm-mode
                                  csharp-mode sml-mode javascript-mode html-mode)
  "The modes which fixme should apply to"
  :group 'fixme-mode)
```

I even added javascript-mode and html-mode to the list, but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way I can make it work for all modes? Is there like an "emacs-mode" that includes all others? If not, why isn't it working on .js files?

Thank you!

Comment: This approach to customizing Emacs is untenable.  You should never modify the source of a library like you've done.  It would be a serious bug in the library if ever have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are emacs emacs inbuilt javascript mode (I guess you are using that) that is `js-mode` not `javascript-mode`

add this .emacs file(~/.emacs.d/init.el)

```
 (add-to-list 'fixme-modes 'js-mode)
```

Generally you don't edit defcustom directly in the source code. `.emacs` is the one for your customizations

UPDATE:
To make fixme-mode to be available for all buffers we should define a global-minor-mode

```
(defun turn-on-fixme-mode ()
  (fixme-mode 1))

(define-global-minor-mode global-fixme-mode
  fixme-mode turn-on-fixme-mode
  :group 'fixme-mode)
```

now call `global-fixme-mode`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Any idea if there's something like a global mode?

Comment: simple way for you is just insert "t" after ":global" at line number 132 in the fixme.el to make it global mode. reload the file or `M-x eval-buffer`